# How can I disable sqlalchemy versioning auto-populate transaction table for running tests?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, database-versioning, sqlalchemy-continuum

I am working with sqlalchemy-continuum to use versioning on selected database tables in a flask app with mssql. In my end-to-end tests I run a flask app context that populates flask's global g object with user information that sqlalchemy-continuum handles via its UserPlugin. The problem is I want to load an exact database state from hand-written json files (using the flask-fixtures library) and I need full control of what is in the database for this. Since sqlalchemy-continuum is auto-populating the transactions table when my json contains data for the versioned tables I am unable to control the user information that is being stored in the transactions table. I want to be able to do something like this in the course of loading the db state from my json 'fixture' file:

```
        # establish if a transaction table is provided in the json state (by me)
        if fixture["model"] == "transaction":
                    special_transaction = fixture
 
        ... 
        # code for loading db state for all 'normal' tables then later:

        if special_transaction is not None:
            statement = text(
                "insert into [transaction] "
                "(issued_at, remote_addr, user_id) "
                "values (:remote_addr, :issued_at, :user_id)"
            )
            session = <the code that gets my session>
            for record in fixture["records"]:
                session.execute(statement, record)
            session.commit()
```

This currently does not work because sqlalchemy-continuum has already 'magically' populated the transaction table by this point so I get clashes trying to add my custom data to it. How can I switch off that behaviour to give me full control of my database state in the test run?

Comment: Besides how to get this working: don't you think you are testing SQLAlchemy Continuum's behavior now, by manipulating the transaction database?

Comment: Thanks Erik van de Ven. Apologies for the long delay. I eventually worked around this issue by toggling the versioning off when loading in my database states then re-toggling it to 'on' and continuing with the testing. This solved the original problem but I still have issues testing foreign key ids that are autogenerated (and thus different depending on the number of tests running in a test suite) which is far from ideal Even re-seeding did not help me there. I wonder how many people there are out there trying to test full database state representations using versioning tables. lonely out here